# Twitch omniauth - Twitch has no control over the content or security of http://localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, twitch

Using `omniauth-twitch` for login with twitch and set

`OAuth Redirect URL = http://localhost:3000/auth/twitch/callback`

```
config.omniauth :twitch, 'xx','xx',
                       redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/twitch/callback'
```

but it gives an error regarding redirect-uri [image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use OAuth in webs without https and of course you can't in localhost, this is a new policy added in 2018.

Comment: I test it on heroku https also but it also gives me same error

Comment: @HaseebAhmad check if the credentials are ok and the require things from twitch, I will check out to help you. Are you using devise?

Comment: Do you think that the problem is twitch and not your code?

Comment: I follow this  blog 
http://alessiofanelli.com/blog/twitch-omniauth-strategy-on-rails

Comment: Could you try using just this and taking off the redirect_uri line? config.omniauth :twitch, ENV.fetch('TWITCH_CLIENT_ID'), ENV.fetch('TWITCH_CLIENT_SECRET')

Comment: I add this in devise.rb with credentials

Comment: Remove the "redirect_uri" from your configuration and tell me what happens. Are you using dotenv?

Comment: no.... what i need to set in oauth redirect url on twitch for heroku?

https://video-portals.herokuapp.com/

Comment: https://video-portals.herokuapp.com/
here is the url...you can test by clicking on login with twitch

Comment: I think i found your problem, for some reason twitch still redirecting you to the localhost, you should set up in twitch your new url for redirection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183499/discussion-between-nicolas-nisoria-and-haseeb-ahmad).